# How to use a templatized data structure in ANOTHER templatized data structure?

Tags: c++, list, templates, dictionary, dynamic-arrays

I have a templatized List class I've written. It has standard List functions (pop_front, push_back. etc.).

I also have a Dictionary class I'm trying to write, **but have come upon a problem** which stops me from using my hashing function.

To resolve possible collisions with my hashing I've decided that my Dictionary class should contain a **dynamic array of Lists.**

---

What I would like to do is index the array of lists in my Dictionary class with my hashing function and insert/get the info I need from there.
**OR** if there is a collision I can chain the Dictionary.

Here is a snippet of my code. I hope someone can look at this and tell me why when I try to index my array of lists in my Dictionary it gives me errors.

( K represents the key I'll be hashing, and T represents the type )

```
template < class K, class T >
class Dictionary
{    
public:  
    void Init( int size );  
    void Insert( K key, T value );  

    int (*Hash)( K key );
private:  
    List< T >* data;
}
```

Here is where the problem begins ... ( i think ):

```
template< class K, class T >  
void Dictionary< K, T >::Init( int size )  
{  
    data = new List< T >[ size ];  
}    

template < class K, class T >  
void Dictionary< K, T >::Insert( K key, T value )  
{  
    int h = Hash( key );  
    //data[ h ].PushBack( value );  //PROBLEM
    //data[ h ]->PushBack( value );  //PROBLEM
}
```

### ----------

Where I've commented out the 2 lines and written "PROMBLEM" is where I am confused ... duh.

To be clear: I only want to PushBack once, not twice. I was simply showcasing that neither syntax will work.

SO: I would like to know how to go through my array of lists( which are templatized by only a
 "class T" ), and insert at whatever index I choose.

---

This is my first post and would appreciate ANY help whatsoever.

### ----------

**EDIT***
It would appear that my code was working perfectly fine. It's just that the intellisense in visual studio wasn't picking the changes up. (And still isn't.)

But it looks like everything is working.

Comment: is missing `<K,T>` in `void Dictionary<K,T>::`s a typo?

Comment: data should be defined to be something like  vector<List< T >>* data  . Also, note that you have to compare the key-value pairs in a bucket, otherwise you may end having multiple copies of same key-value pairs in the buckets if they are inserted multiple times.

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? What problem have you come upon? Your code doesn't compile? Post the **specific** error message you are getting.